# How to Create the Next Query to Group By

Tags: mysql

I have those queries:

`SELECT COUNT(*) AS numofrows, disposition,region FROM  total_disposition_report WHERE disposition='ANSWERED'  GROUP BY region ;`

`SELECT COUNT(*) AS numofrows, disposition,region FROM  total_disposition_report WHERE disposition='BUSY'  GROUP BY region ;`

`SELECT COUNT(*) AS numofrows, disposition,region FROM  total_disposition_report WHERE disposition='...'  GROUP BY region ;`

`SELECT COUNT(*) AS numofrows, disposition,region FROM  total_disposition_report WHERE disposition='...'  GROUP BY region ;`

Is there any chance top get the same effect in one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `disposition` to the `group by`:

e.g.:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS numofrows, disposition,region FROM total_disposition_report GROUP BY region, disposition;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS numofrows, disposition,region 
FROM total_disposition_report 
WHERE disposition IN ('ANSWERED', 'BUSY', '...') 
GROUP BY region, disposition ;
```